# R, Run an experiment 100000 times in R

Tags: r, statistics, analytics

I´ve generated the following values in r as an experiment:

```
>  q<- matrix(rbinom(10*1000,1,0.5),ncol=10)
>  for( i in 1:10){
+  a=a+q[1,i]
+ }
> a<-a/10
> 
> k<-sample(1:1000,1)
> b<-0
> for(i in 1:10){
+ b=b+q[k,i]
+ }
> b<-b/10
> 
> c<-rowMeans(q)
> c<-min(q)
```

So, what I want is to repeat the experiment 100000 times. For example, generating the matrix q 100000 times, the same as a,b and c. Finally, I want a vector which returns the mean of a, the mean of b and the mean of c as a result of the 100000 iterations.

Adding information:
   I´ve done what you suggested :
But it gives me following message:

```
> means<-rowMeans(replicate(100000,wrapper))
Error in rowMeans(replicate(1e+05, wrapper)) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

Last edition:
It was just a problem of (), I mean, it works in the following way:

```
> means<-rowMeans(replicate(100000,wrapper()))
```

Comment: Customary warning: don't name anything "c", since this is an R function. You can see it in use a couple times in Manetheran's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the `replicate` function:

```
# Wrap your code above into a function that returns a, b, and c
wrapper <- function() {
  # Your code goes here
  return(c(a,b,c))
}

means <- rowMeans(replicate(100000, wrapper()))
names(means) <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

Comment: I´ve used your suggestion but it gives me the message which I show in the principal post.

Comment: Sorry, i really should have picked that up considering i ran into the same issue myself formatting the answer!

Comment: Parentheses are the source of, and the answer to, all of life's bugs (stealing from H. Simpson)!

Comment: At least there was closure on this one!